# Java identifying more than 2 monitors

Tags: java, multiple-monitors

I am developing an Java swing based application which will 3 distinct main JFrames and each one of these will have to be displayed on one of the three display-monitors present in the system. Moreover application is going to have capability to alertif a particular display-monitor gone disconnected or reconnecetd.

Each main-JFrame must be displayed on a specific display-screen. This is due to the place where these monitors are going to be located. More like a point of sale scenario where one monitor can show things for sale-person and other for client and other for a security person.

Now the main issue is how to know which monitor is which. I solved this issue by getting serial-no of each monitor by calling a VBScript from within Java.

But still another problem is how map serial-no information of the monitor in Java. In Java what I can get corresponding to each monitor is a java.awt.GraphicsDevice instance and I have no idea how I can map serial-no information to this as the only way to have these instances of java.awt.GraphicsDevice is GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices() and this function does not ensure that it will return the devices in a sepecific sequence, each time the function is called.

Thanking in anticipation

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888131/determine-windows-display-number-and-or-layout-via-java

Comment: in cases when mirror display is selected ,than this methods will return only one screen . Do you know any solution of this ??

Answer (score 2):

Java supports multiple monitors via a GraphicsEnvironment and GraphicsDevice objects. Check the [GraphicsDevice](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html) javadoc for more info.

Comment: Already I am reading serial-nos from property file but the problem with using the result of getIDstring, even if it is stable, is that still i can not predetermine which serial-no corresponds to which getIDstring's result

Comment: I think you meant to respond to my answer, I will update my answer to add another suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Does the [`GraphicsDevice.getIDString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#getIDstring%28%29) method give you a stable value that you can compare against the serial numbers? If so, you can write all identified serial numbers to a property file, and do a comparison each time your program starts (if the ID isn't already the serial num). This property file could also store the position of each display (left, center, right or top, middle, bottom, etc)

If you cannot determine the correspondance between the id and the serial number, you could trigger a 'display setup routine' whenever you see an display id that is not in your properties file.

This routine would prompt the user to confirm the display model number and enter the position of each display (consider the display orientation settings in Win,OS X, Linux etc). If you can draw widgets to a specific display, you should be able to collect this information. Also, if the user rearranges the physical position of their displays (perhaps swapping the position of two displays), then they could manually execute this routine.