# Get location of secondary monitor. (right of /left of Primary)

Tags: java, multiple-monitors

I am working on a programm which needs to find objects on a screen, works fine so far, but I got a problem with multi-monitor configurations.

The `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()`-class is able to give almost all details I need to define my search-area over multiple Screens but not the order of the devices. (e.g. secondary monitor is right of primary).

Therefore I am looking for a way to find out the screen-locations of primary and secondary monitors in, Java.

Comment: Maybe this question would be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888131/determine-windows-display-number-and-or-layout-via-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try reading [`GraphicsDevice.html#getIDstring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#getIDstring%28%29) value to determine ID of the monitor.

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.
getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
for (int j = 0; j < gs.length; j++) { 
   GraphicsDevice gd = gs[j];
   System.out.println("ID#: " + gd.getDeviceID());
}
```

Gives this for me:

```
ID#: \Display0
ID#: \Display1
```

Remember, that sometimes secondary monitor can be to the left of the primary. In this case, it will have negative bounds.

In order to determine whole bounds of the screen area, you can use an example, provided at the JDK Javadocs site:
[`GraphicsConfiguration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html)

Comment: I was looking for a min and max screen values with multiple monitors and the GraphicsConfiguration Javadoc example (with a couple of small calculations) gave me exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to derive this from the x and y coordinates of each device.

Comment: Yes that probably would work: ´screenDevices[i].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().x);´ and ´screenDevices[i].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().y);´ return the absolute position from there on it's just simple math... thanks a lot sometimes it's just to obivous... -.-

Answer (score 0):

The x and y coordinates will put the secondary screen on the right.

However, there's no way you'll know whether the primary screen is physically on the left, in the center, or on the right.  That's up to the person that plugged the monitors in.

Actually, there is a way to configure 9 panels on one workstation.  (I wish I had this.)  So screen orientation is up to the user.